# How do I do this in excel 2010, sum of function array?

Tags: excel-2010

I want to do this: `SUM(Function(A1:A6))`. Currently only `SUM(Function(A1),Function(A2), ... Function(A6))` seems do-able. Please help!

Very specifically I have a macro function TD(x,y), where x and y are single variables
Now I want to do SUM(TD(x1:x10,y))

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the formula using your first version if you hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in Excel 2010.  This will make it an array based formula.  For instance, this should work fine:

```
=SUM(A1:A6^2)
```

---

**EDIT**: To use a user-defined function, you have to modify your function to take an array parameter.  When you press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, it treats all ranges as parameters directly into your function and expects all functions applied to take range parameters and return an array result.  Here is an example with a hypothetical function `TD(x, y) = x + y` that just returns the sum of the two parameters:

```
Function TD(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
    TD = x + y
End Function
```

Function `TD` is the base function that we are defining as explained above.

```
Function TDArray(ByVal x As Variant, ByVal y As Variant) As Integer()
    Dim xc() As Integer
    Dim yc() As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    If TypeName(x) = "Range" Then
        xc = GetRangeValues(x)
        count = UBound(xc)
    End If

    If TypeName(y) = "Range" Then
        yc = GetRangeValues(y)
        count = UBound(yc)
    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xVal As Integer
    Dim yVal As Integer
    Dim result() As Integer
    ReDim result(1 To count)
    For i = 1 To count
        If TypeName(x) = "Range" Then xVal = xc(i) Else xVal = x
        If TypeName(y) = "Range" Then yVal = yc(i) Else yVal = y
        result(i) = TD(xVal, yVal)
    Next

    TDArray = result
End Function
```

Function `TDArray` is a function that mirrors the functionality of `TD`, but is also able to take an array as a parameter.  It works by accepting `Variant` parameters and then checking to see if a Range or an integer was passed.  If a Range was passed, it is converted into an array, and the function `TD` is applied to each element in the array.  The result then is returned as an array to the next function, which in this example would be the call to `SUM`.

```
Function GetRangeValues(ByVal r As Range) As Integer()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim result() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim result(1 To r.Cells.count)

    i = 1
    For Each c In r
        result(i) = c.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
    GetRangeValues = result
End Function
```

Function `GetRangeValues` is a simple helper function that takes a Range parameter and converts it into an array which is easier to navigate because it can be iterated by index.  Armed with these function definitions, it would now be possible to enter the following function into a cell, and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, and get the expected result (note we use the array form `TDArray` - if you are applying the calculation to a pair of parameters, say `TD(A4,A5)`, then you use `TD`; for any ranges, you must use `TDArray`):

```
=SUM(TDArray(X1:X10,y))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's cool. Suppose it's a user-defined function(not Excel function)?

Comment: Very specifically I have a macro function TD(x,y), where x and y are single variables
Now I want to do SUM(TD(x1:x10,y))

Comment: From my testing, it looks like you have to modify your function to take a `Range` object, and return an array if you want it to participate in an array-based formula.  I whipped up a proto-type and will post it on here later tonight when I get more time.  It will probably be a lot easier just to use another column to store the result of `TD(x,y)` and then sum the result.